# How to check if cv2.circle lies inside cv2.rectangle in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I have an opencv application where I am detecting face. I have drawn a `circle` on frame and I need to check if the circle lies inside the bounding box of the face or not. Below is the code to draw circle

```
cv2.circle(frame, (293, 141), 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```

which means x is 293 and y is 141 for circle. Below is the code for face detection:

```
face_bbox = face.detect_face(frame)
    if face_bbox is not None:
        (f_startX, f_startY, f_endX, f_endY) = face_bbox.astype("int")
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (f_startX, f_startY), (f_endX, f_endY), (0, 0, 0), 2)
```

`f_startX, f_startY, f_endX, f_endY` are the coordinates of the rectangle drawn for face. Now I need to check if circle lies between the bounding box or not. For this I have put below condition:

```
if f_startX < 293 < f_endX and f_startY > 141 > f_endY:
   print("Circle is inside face")
else:
  print("Circle is outside face")
```

But this seems not to be working. I am also a bit confuse as to how I should compare the x and y of face with x and y of circle. Can anyone please suggest me a good way. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Look at the two conditions you wrote  -- do you notice any discrepancy between the one for X coordinate and the one for Y coordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working and this is the condition I use:

```
if f_startX < 293 < f_endX and f_startY < 141 < f_endY:
    print("Circle is inside face")
else:
    print("Circle is outside face")
```

Comment: This way, you're considering only the center of the circle. Is this right for your purpose? The question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

I am putting a very generic solution.
Replace the variable accordingly.

```py
#circle center
center_x = some_value
center_y = some_value
radius = some_value
(f_startX, f_startY, f_endX, f_endY) = face_bbox.astype("int")

if (center_x + radius < f_endX) and (center_y + radius < f_endY) and\ 
(center_x - radius > f_startX) and (center_y - radius >  f_startY):
     print("Inside")
else:
     print("Outside")
```

Comment: Note that in python you can chain comparisons: `a < b < c >= d == e` is equivalent to `a < b and b < c and c >= d and d == e`. In the chained version, each "value" (a, b, c, d, e) is evaluated only once, and evaluation stops at the first false result. Also, `a` and `c` do not compare to each other, so `a < b > c` is also possible. More on: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons